# How to display an item from dropdown in php (no database)

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown and i want to show the value which is selected.

i have tried

```
    <select name ="dd">
    <option> option1 </option>
    <option> option2 </option>
    <option> option3 </option>
    </select>
    <?php 
    $a = $_POST["dd"];
    echo $a; ?>
```

But it always shows undefined index :dd

Comment: Have you post that select input with form?

Comment: I think as @MihirBhatt is pointing you have not done a form submission

Comment: yup , but the   form action = another page.

Comment: you have to use form and submit button also...

Comment: i want to show that before submission . jus when some one selects it should show what they selected then submission

Comment: @Avinash you have to use javascript for these kind of actions

Answer (score 0):

YOu must use value Atribiute like bellow,

```
<option value="option1" >option1</option>
```

then your code will work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You just need a value attribute in your html** - You also need to add a form and a button.

```
<FORM method="post" action="yourpage.php">
<select name ="dd">
<option  value="option1"> option1 </option>
<option value="option2"> option2</option>
<option value="option3"> option3 </option>
</select>
<INPUT name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</FORM>
```

**Or you can simply get the value using javascript:**
Your Html will need a id:

```js
document.getElementById("myselect").onchange = function() {
  alert(document.getElementById("myselect").value);
}
```

```html
<select name="dd" id="myselect">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have something, which will have a value what you selected. For example, let's say, that this  is in form with method="post".

Then, after clicking the submit button, your selection is stored in $_POST["dd"]. So you can compare, if value of option is equal to value in a $_POST. If yes, add an attribute "selected" So for example, your select can look like:

```
<select name ="dd">
    <option value="1" <?=(($_POST["dd"]==1)?"selected":"")?>> option1 </option>
    <option value="2" <?=(($_POST["dd"]==2)?"selected":"")?>> option2 </option>
    <option value="3" <?=(($_POST["dd"]==3)?"selected":"")?>> option3 </option>
    </select>
```

You can also compare string values in , but don't forget to use "" or '' if you are writting down string